# Form1 should be closed and Form3 should be opened but both are opened

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an version checker and in the code it is assumed that form1 should be closed and form3 should be opened but both are opened.

[image: App when new update require]

Following is the code of the version check, in the pastebin it says 0.5 and that's when I put the different version for the users.

```
private void ROXPLOIT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();
    string Script = wb.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/LGGkpfBL");
    if (Script == "v0.5 ")
    {

    }
    else
    {
      Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
      frm3.Show();
      Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
      frm1.Close();
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to get version. Closing Program.");
    this.Close();
  }
}
```

This is where it should be changed but I don't know how.

```
{
  Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
  frm3.Show();
  Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
  frm1.Close();
}
```

Please do let me know if you need more detail. I am new to this.

Comment: `Form1 frm1 = new Form1();` `frm1.Close();`  You are creating a "new" Form1, then closing it right away.

Comment: You probably want to close the **current Instance** of `Form1`. Of course you cannot just create a **new Instance** of that Class and close that. What's the point? Btw, Is, by chance, `Form1` the starting Form of your application? What is `ROXPLOIT`? Another Form? What is the *relation* between this Form and `Form1`? Note that you always have an `OpenForms` collection that you can inspect.

Comment: So how should I do to close Form1

Comment: Don't you have access to the current Instance of Form1? To close it using the `OpenForms` collections: `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault()?.Close();`. But you should have code that can access all the objects you need a reference to.

Comment: Jimi i am new on this, can you be more specify, i dont move very good C#

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing following, you are creating new instance of the `Form1`. Instead you should be calling `Close()` method on the instance of the Form1 that was used to show the `Form1`.

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.Close();
```

To resolve this problem you should be able to use instance of the `Form1` that showed the form in first place. Make variable declaration of type `Form1` a class level member so that you are able to reference it later in class methods. You could do something like following.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DNF_Win_Forms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form2 myForm2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myForm2 = new Form2();
            myForm2.Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            myForm2.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am making `myForm2` a class level member so that I can reference it later in class methods.

Comment: i dont understand, what i need to do exactly

Comment: @Maniust, Can you update your question and add code about how you are displaying Form1?

Answer (score 0):

am also a new contributor on stackoverflow but i hope this works. I would be taking an excerpt from your code for better illustration.

```
  private void ROXPLOIT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
  try
  {
    WebClient wb = new WebClient();
    string Script = wb.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/LGGkpfBL");
    if (Script == "v0.5 ")
    {

    }
    else
    {
      this.Hide();
      Form3 form3 = new Form3();
      form3.Show();
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to get version. Closing Program.");
    

  }
}
```

Since you are currently on the Form1 class, their is actually no need to instantiate it. Instantiate the Form3 Class, then that form can easily be shown afterwards with the Show() method. I hope this helps. *The change i made is actually in the else part of the IF statement*